# Conseguir Biblioteca ImageApp

Tags: javascript, google-hoja-de-cálculo, librería

Dispongo de un código en javascript para poder cortar una imagen en varias partes en las coordenadas que deseo, pero necesito una biblioteca con la funcion ImageApp. El problema es que la iD de la biblioteca que me han facilitado, la introduzco a la hora de instalarla en el script de google sheets y me dice que esa biblioteca no la encuentra.
Alguien me podría decir donde encontrar esa biblioteca, porque por más que la he buscado no consigo encontrarla. Gracias.

Comment: Hola Héctor, y el nombre de la biblioteca es....

Comment: El problema es que lo desconozco

Comment: De casualidad, será [esta](https://download.freedownloadmanager.org/Windows-PC/ImageApp/FREE-1.0.0.html?ac64942)?.

Comment: Te agradezco la ayuda. El problema es que he abierto el archivo y hay miles de archivos y mis nociones no me dan para saber que archivo es el que tengo que instalar como libreria. La verdad es que ando muy perdido. Aun asi mil gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Si la aplicación es la que buscas, [aquí](https://imageapp.sourceforge.net/v4.0/main.html#installation.html) tienes una guía de instalación.